# The meaning of the phrase "to delay the time to occurrence of mood episodes"

Tags: technical, medical

I'm not exactly sure what this phrase mean:
"the purpose of _ is to delay the time to occurrence of mood episodes ..."

My guess is that it means that _ increases the amount of time between episodes.

Comment: That's probably what's intended. But "the time to occurrence" is a duration, a period of time, which should be extended rather than deferred.

Comment: As a *common* English sentence (i.e. not from a *specialised* field), it is a claim to increase the time before the start of those mood episodes. That is, if the episodes would have started at time *t* without `_`, then applying `_` is claimed to lead to a later start time than *t*. However, given the `medical` tag, there may be medical terminology involved that I am not familiar with.

Comment: My guess it that it's poorly worded.

Answer (score 1):

**"postpone"** seems to fit.

"the purpose of _ is to postpone the occurrence of mood episodes ..."

> - **postpone** - (vb)  To cause or arrange for (an event) to take place at a time later than the time at which it was originally supposed to happen.

[**Does B.C.G. vaccination prevent or postpone the occurrence of tuberculous meningitis?**](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10830036)

This new drug is supposed **to postpone the occurrence** of anxiety attacks.

She has decided **to postpone the meeting**.

**Our departure was postponed** because of the weather.